# change date into words in php

Tags: php, date

I have an array of dates which are in the format 20100808 (YYYYMMD). How can i change this into August 08 2010? I am using php.

I cannot change the date array format. It will be in 20100808 only.

Comment: Consider opening another question for your newly added request

Comment: i think i will if i do not get a reply at all...;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using PHP 5.3:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('Ymd', '20100808');

echo $date->format('F d Y')
```

If not you could try:

```
echo date('F d Y', strtotime('20100808'));
```

Comment: thanks ... made some modifications according to my code and your second solution clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) to convert the string to a timestamp, and [`date`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format the timestamp as a new string:

```
$dates = array(20100808, ...);
foreach($dates as $date)
    echo date("F d Y", strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
dateTime = new DateTime('YYYYMMD');
echo $dateTime->format('M jS Y');
```

i.e.

```
dateTime = new DateTime('20100808');
```